# Computing confidence intervals for non-independent data

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, independence

I am using the `survey` package in R to t-test data that not independent (it is a time series) by creating a `survey` object and identifying different months as "clusters" and then t-testing to see if the mean (over a whole year) is different from 0. The data looks something like this:

```
ID    Y    month
1    .5      1
2    .24     1
3    .36     1
...  
200  .44     12
```

I create a `survey` object with the following line:

```
clusterdat<- svydesign(id=~month,data=mydata)
```

then t-test ($H_a: \mu \neq 0$)

```
svyttest(y~0, design=mydata)
```

The output contains a t-statistic, corresponding p-value, degrees of freedom, and the sample mean, but there is no option to calculate a confidence interval. Am I missing something? If not, how might I compute one myself? Is the $t^*$ for 95% confidence in this case the same as for a regular t-test (i.e. could I look it up by df in a regular $t$ table)? How would I compute the sample standard deviation for this data?

Comment: Are you doing spearate tests for individual months?  Is the correlation only across months with the cases within a given month independent of each other?

Comment: Yes, the correlation is only between months, not within. I am testing the mean over one year, not for each month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are combining months in the analysis the correlation between months affects how you compute the test statistic and/or confidence interval because you have to scale the mean difference by its standard error.  The variance of sums in this case is not just the sum of the variances but it also includes terms like $2 \cdot {\rm cov}(X_i,X_j)$ for $i ≠ j$.  If there is a high degree of positive correlation this variance will be a lot larger than hand the variables been uncorrelated.  If they were highly negatively correlated it could be smaller. So you encounter two problems (1) get a good estimate of the standard error, (2) identify a good approximating distribution for the test statistic under the null hypothesis.

Comment: @ Michael Chernick Thanks! This was a much better explanation than I was able to find elsewhere. Any suggestions on how to find the SE in R? I think the data is approximately normal (I checked with several normality tests).

Comment: It is easy enough to write down a formula for the variance and hence from that the standard error. It is given as Var(∑Xi)= ∑Var(Xi) +2 ∑∑Cov(Xi,Xj) where the double sum for the covariance terms is taken for all i ≠ j.

Comment: Michael, how would you estimate these covariances? Also, assuming we're talking about a $t$-test here, it's not completely obvious to me what the right degrees of freedom would be for the $t$-statistic that is normalized by the "adjusted" standard error that includes the covariances. Since we're estimating the covariances as well as the variance, I'd guess the DFs would be lower than what we'd have under independence. Also, when there's positive correlation in the data, your "effective sample size" is lessened, so that's another reason I'd expected the DFs to be smaller. Any ideas?

Comment: (That is, if the test statistic even has a $t$ distribution anymore)

Comment: I think the test statistic does have an approximate t distribution very much analogous to the Satterwaite approximation in the unequal variance case.  T with fractional degrees of freedom and less than the dfs for the independent case when correlations are highly positive.  To estimate the correlation you might need to assume stationarity and use all the lag k month terms for each autocovariance.  Not a lot of data so you probably don't get very good estimates.